# how to determine which of the installed chrome extensions are showing text-enhanced ads or are injecting new CSS class names?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, css

I have three google users [personal, work, work] in my chrome on Mac OS X.

The chrome for my personal account [not the other two chromes] has text-enhanced ads in every site i go to. It double-underlines some keywords on every page. On mouse hover I get an ad overlay from http[colon][slash][slash]`intext.nav-links.com`[slash]

Upon right-clicking one of the text-enhanced keywords and going to 'inspect element', i see that the text has been wrapped around with a CSS classname called `adtext`. It even shows the `.adtext` CSS descriptions on the right.

How do i determine from WHICH particular extension is this CSS classname being injected into my pages?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it there are 3 options:

1. Inspect element on the ad (look for clues), and take a look at the resources page.  See if there are any outgoing requests that you can tie to a particular extension.
2. Disable an extension, reload the page, if the add is still there, cross that one off your list of suspects and try again.
3. Dive into the code of the extension by clicking on the background page, and opening up the inspector.  You will probably looking for some AJAX request to an ad server. This could be difficult depending on how obfuscated the code is, and how many extensions you have.

Best of luck!